# Use Activities instead of Fragments in a Sliding Menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, slidingmenu

I have a sliding menu with some Fragments, but i want to change it with Activities, is it possible?

```
private void replaceFragment(int pos) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new X();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Y();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Z();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new X();
            break;
    }

    if (null != fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

I don't know how to change the last part of the code. --> FragmentManager and --> FragmentTransaction. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not using ViewPager in my app

Comment: Sliding Menu in my app, is that menu in the left side, and when i click on an item, I want another activity to appear. I want to switch because, i have no idea how to work with Fragments and it takes me a lot, to find what i want :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use Activity in place of fragment, But
you have following challenges.

1. You need to implement sliding drawer on every activity, if you uses fragment then HomeActivity sliding drawer will be shown  on all fragment

update your code like this if you want to implement activity

```
private void replaceFragment(int pos) {
    Intent intent = null;
    Context context = this;
    switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
            break;
        case 1:
            intent = new Intent(context, ThirdActivity.class);
            break;
        case 2:
            intent =  new Intent(context, FourthActivity.class);
            break;
        default:
            intent = new Intent(context, DefaultActivity.class);
            break;
    }

    if (intent != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```